# Разместить Div после определнного кол-ва символов

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

Нужно в теле статьи сделать вывод похожих публикаций по тегу. Другими словами необходимо в тексте сразу по нескольким условиям вывести

`<div><?php echo $this->item->related; ?></div>`

**Какие условия для вывода div?**

Например, Div должен быть выведен не менее, чем после 400 символов в конце абзаца, при условии, что полный объем статьи не менее 600 символов. 
Если даже количество символов в абзаце более 400 (например, 600-1000) все равно вывести в конце абзаца.

Фрагмент кода, который отвечает за вывод текста статьи

```
<div style="display: inline-block;" class="itemFullText_Blog_Grid">    
   <?php echo $this->item->fulltext; ?> 
</div>
```

Благодарю за помощь! Спасибо!

Comment: Что внутри $this->item->fulltext? html код или просто текст?

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev внутри  $this->item->fulltext код <?php echo $this->item->related; ?>

Comment: Ну сделайте обрезание текста mb_substr() для $this->item->fulltext и установите нужный див.

Comment: @Arsen  а оставшийся текст как вывести ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот примерно так:

```
    <?php
    $text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc imperdiet tristique eros in";

    $beforetext = mb_substr($text, 0, 10, 'utf-8');
    $aftertext = mb_substr($text, 11, 10000, 'utf-8');


    echo $beforetext;
    echo $this->item->related;
    echo $aftertext;
```